# How to get around an illegal octal digit in a url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my rails app that saves the image from an og:image tag url.

```
def photo_from_url(url)
  if !Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").blank?
    photo_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).css("meta[property='og:image']").first.attributes["content"]
    self.photo = URI.parse(photo_url)
    self.save
  end
end
```

This works in most cases, except when the image url happens to include a number that start with 0, such as `http://ad009cdnb.website.com/rest-of-url`

In these cases, I get an illegal octal digit error.

How can I prevent the method from thinking that any numbers starting with zero are base-8?

Comment: Are you sure you want to save photo as a URI::HTTP? Shouldn't that just be a String?

Comment: I ended up here again. My comment above might not be all that relevant, but right now it doesn't quite make sense. What method is it that's failing? `photo=`, `URI.parse` or `save`?

Comment: Hi @Frans.  Seems I can't reproduce the error.... Man, now I"m really confused. Before, I was getting an illegal octal digit, but now the same link works fine... I'll try to reproduce the error, and if I can't, I'll close the question...

Comment: a stack trace would help immensely

Comment: Which gem (if any) are you using to handle photo attachments?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a answer. Sorry for use the system wrongly. Can't find out how to put a string with HTTP without change it in a link as comment.

URI.parse works fine:

```
URI.parse("http://ad009cdnb.website.com/rest-of-url").to_s
=> "http://ad009cdnb.website.com/rest-of-url"
```

as everyone said, we really need a stacktrace or something to help you. And most likely you will want to save the URL as a string, not as an object on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I posted this question, but I can no longer reproduce the question.

As this is no longer an issue, I think the best course of action is to close this question. However, I see that some people have been voted up for their comments (They make good points like saving as a string instead of an object). Will they be discredited if the questions is closed?

I'm grateful for everyone's input, and don't want to upset anyone. What is SO protocol for a situation like this?

Comment: I'm not a great contributor of SO myself, so wrong person to answer, but  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question